# definite or indefinite article here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> The tiger, who died promptly before James died, was a/the representation of James.

It is a sentence made in my head. If I say "the" here, even if I have not mentioned this representation to anyone before, I think it will imply that there is only one representation.

But if I say "a" there, I think it will imply that there are several more representations. However, on the other hand, I think it also can be used, for this idea is introduced for the first time.

Which interpretation of mine is correct?

Comment: Both interpretations are correct, except I would say *a representation* implies that there *may be* (not *are*) other representations. (In general, this whole guideline of *first mention* is only correct sometimes. Go read any modern English text and count how often *the* is used when a noun is a 'first mention'. It's less than 1/3 of the time, I believe.)

Comment: @whitedevil Only you can know the answer! Is the tiger only one of several representations of James? Then "a" is correct. Is there no other rerepresentation? Then "the" is correct. Only you know the context.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Is it a similar example? "teacher is pointing at a/the written topic on the white board.". I think both are acceptable, with "the" emphasizing that this is the topic she is pointing at, regardless of how many topics there are, and "a" providing the sense that there may be more than one topic on the whiteboard, but is used because there is no intention to emphasize. Also this: "it is hard to derive a perfect understanding from a/the context". "The" emphasizes  that _context_ in the sentence is the one you are trying to gain a perfect understanding from, while "a" is generalizing...

Comment: ...the kind of context. Am I right?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Please see above :) I want your explanation for this, if possible.

Comment: @whitedevil RIght, slightly, but in a larger sense neither right nor wring. You seem to be hoping for _rules_ where there are none. In many cases, the choice of article is the writer's, based upon context, rhythm, style, or even whim.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Oh, not rules. Just nuance.

Comment: @whitedevil All right then. Take your sentence above: _The tiger, who died promptly before James died, was the representation of James._ I might write that if what I meant were: _The tiger was the very image of James._ On the other hand, if I wrote: _The tiger, who died promptly before James died, was a representation of James._ ... I might mean _The tiger, among other animals, was a representation of James._

Answer (score 2):

> The tiger, who died promptly before James died, was a/the representation of James.

Yes, regardless of the rather dubiously-helpful status of 'first mention', *the representation* does, within the context of this isolated sentence, imply that there is only one representation, while *a* implies that there *may be* more representation.

From your comments:

> teacher is pointing at a/the written topic on the white board.
>
> I think both are acceptable, with "the" emphasizing that this is the topic she is pointing at, regardless of how many topics there are, and "a" providing the sense that there may be more than one topic on the whiteboard, but is used because there is no intention to emphasize.

Yes, both could be possible. It is not really a matter of emphasis. It is just a matter of signalling to the reader the same information as the articles did in your example with *a/the representation*. One cannot talk about everything an indefinite or definite noun phrase is doing, or could be doing, in a sentence that has zero context. In a larger context, *the topic* could be the one under discussion, as opposed to others that are not, In this case, *the* is doing a job that it frequently/usually does: telling the hearer that he should be able to identify *which topic* the speaker is referring to.

> it is hard to derive a perfect understanding from a/the context.
>
> *The* emphasizes that context in the sentence is the one you are trying to gain a perfect understanding from, while *a* is generalizing.

Rather than *emphasize* I prefer the word *signal*. The articles usually signal  something to the reader. Very often, *the* in a noun phrase signals to the reader that the reader should be able to identify the referent (*which* thing the speaker is referring to). *The context* means *the context that I believe/assume that you can identify*.

On the other hand, a definite noun phrase such as *the context* can, in some contexts, signal to the reader that I am going to make the referent the subject of what I am going to talk about next, and after I do, you will be able to identify it:

> That's when the tall guy got here.

*What* tall guy? *Which* tall guy? The tall guy I am about to tell you about.

The indefinite article does not send the same signal. It is, as you say, just generalizing. *A* can imply that there may be more than one of something. This is probably what it is doing in all of your examples.

On the other hand, in some contexts, *a* is used more like *one* (this is not surprising, because the indefinite article *an* came from the word *one*):

> I have a bicycle and two cars.

*A* very often means no more than *one* here.

Keep reading Abbott. I don't know if you have read her [definite and indefinite](http://philpapers.org/go.pl?id=ABBDAI-2&proxyId=none&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msu.edu%2F%257Eabbottb%2Fdef%26inde.pdf) (pdf). It is one of several that she has written that have similar titles.

---

From  comment:

> I like to write the stuffs down on the book when I annotate a book.

First of all *[stuff](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stuff)* is a mass noun and not used in the plural. If someone said *stuffs* they were using the word in a rare and unusual manner, perhaps humorously. (The word *[foodstuff](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foodstuff)* is used as a count noun.)

Here, in both cases *the* is used to signal to the reader or hearer that he or she should be able to identify *which stuff* and *which book* the speaker is talking about. The speaker assumes the hearer can identify *which stuff* and *which book* he means. As a matter of fact, I personally *cannot* do this, and I have no idea which stuff and which book are  being talked about. There would have to be some other way–existing outside of the text of this sentence–for me to identify which ones he means.

*One* of these ways is that the speaker could have mentioned them before. This is where  the so-called first mention guideline comes into play (I could never call it a *rule* because it simply isn't.)

*Another* way is that he is holding the book in his hand and obviously referring to it as *the book*. Again, this is not so much an emphasis  but a subtle signal: there's no other book in sight, so he must be talking about the one he's holding. In this case he could also say *this book*.

Likewise, perhaps it is obvious from context *which stuff* he is talking about. For instance, if this sentence was said during a video  and it is clear *which book* and *which stuff* the speaker is talking about, then the speaker can use the definite article with them.

Comment: Thank you. I recently heard someone say this sentence; "I like to write the _stuffs_ down on the _book_ when I annotate a book". There are two uses of the definite article. I do not understand how these are legitimate. But here is my best guess; I think "stuffs" takes on the definite article because it is readily known that the stuffs are what he writes down on the book, not just any other stuffs. With the book, it is possible that the definite article signals that this is the book that  something is being written on, not just any book. Am I correct about it?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Maybe I misheard the stuffs. But "the book", this I definitely heard. And there was no video, book in his hand, nor was it mentioned before. Though I have a guess. "When I annotate a book, I like to write stuff down on the book." This book is mentioned in the when-clause. Might it be the reason?

Comment: Yes *the book* is now the definite book of the generalized *a book* of the when-clause.

Comment: And it is not possible to say "when I annotate a book, I like to write stuff down on a book." Am I right?

Comment: That is strange. Does it mean that if I say "the" book in the second clause, "a" book was actually a specific book, whereas "a"book in the second clause and another "a" book in the first clause mean that both of them are just general?

Comment: Actually, one can say that. One could be referring to *a book in general* in both clauses.

Comment: Why don't you ask that as a new question post, asking about the difference in the two sentences.... It's too complicated to deal with in comments.

Comment: Can we move it to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43837/discussion-between-whitedevil-and-alan-carmack).

Comment: well, something happened and the chat room is no longer allowing me to write anything or let me back in, now that I have exited.. grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: I am back in the chat room after rebooting computer.

Comment: Well, again, the chat room suddenly stopped working for me. I could see what you typed, but I could not type anything in response.

Comment: If I say "I read the books you gave me" I am telling you that should be able to identify *which books* I mean; whether you have given me only two books ever, or you have given me 1000 books over 20 years... of course, context and shared knowledge come into play: these sentences are not usually uttered with no context.